# Query related Rest Api in ErpNext

Tags: erpnext

I am trying to fetch data and filter data from erpnext customized site.
When i fetch the fields of the doctype i use the url:- `https://runga.rungamatteegroup.com/api/resource/Tea%20Invoice?fields=["name","grade","status","invpr","invsuf","estatename","dop"]`
I get the data absolutely fine.
When i fetch the data with filtration, using the url:- `https://runga.rungamatteegroup.com/api/resource/Tea%20Invoice/?filters=[["Tea%20Invoice",%20"status",%20"=",%20"Sold%20&%20Delivered"]]`
I get the data absolutely fine.

When i try to merge the fields and filter in the url as querystring , i am not able to get it together. the url is :-

```
https://runga.rungamatteegroup.com/api/resource/Tea%20Invoice/?fields=["status","name","dop"]?filters=[["Tea%20Invoice",%20"status",%20"=",%20"Sold%20&%20Delivered"]]
```

I am trying this to get the fields of the filtered data only.Because fetching all the data and then filtering will be very hectic.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://runga.rungamatteegroup.com/api/resource/Tea%20Invoice/?fields=["status","name","dop"]&filters=[["Tea%20Invoice",%20"status",%20"=",%20"Sold%20&%20Delivered"]]
```

This will work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See:  [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Filters and Fields sections are seperated by "&" sign, not with a question mark.
So your query should be:

```
https://runga.rungamatteegroup.com/api/resource/Tea%20Invoice/?fields=["status","name","dop"]&filters=[["Tea%20Invoice",%20"status",%20"=",%20"Sold%20&%20Delivered"]]
```